# Object's attribute in method

Tags: java

I got a matrix of objects (pixels), and I want to call for the length method on the matrix ('''_image.length''').
Do I need to write down the _image part, or does it understand that this is the only attribute the matrix object has?

This is the code im working on as example (goal is to flip the image horizontally):

```
public void flipHorizontal()
{
    RGBColor tempPixel = new RGBColor();
    for(int i = 0;i < _image.length;i++)
        //_image[i].length - j half the array once we reach the center
        //_image[i].length - j - 1 will always be the more right pixel we are copying
        for(int j = 0;j < _image[i].length - j;j++) {
            //back-up the pixel we are about to overwrite
            tempPixel.setRed(_image[i][j].getRed());
            tempPixel.setGreen(_image[i][j].getGreen());
            tempPixel.setBlue(_image[i][j].getBlue());
            //overwrite the left pixel
            _image[i][j].setRed(_image[i][_image[i].length - j - 1].getRed());//
            _image[i][j].setGreen(_image[i][_image[i].length - j - 1].getGreen());
            _image[i][j].setBlue(_image[i][_image[i].length - j - 1].getBlue());
            //overwrite the right pixel
            _image[i][_image[i].length - j - 1].setRed(tempPixel.getRed());
            _image[i][_image[i].length - j - 1].setGreen(tempPixel.getGreen());
            _image[i][_image[i].length - j - 1].setBlue(tempPixel.getBlue());
        }
}
```

Still a student here, so pls no suggesting more efficient methods of writing this that do not involve private methods, arrays and loops (cant use anything more advanced anyways).

Comment: I'm mainly looking for a way to shorten the `_image[i][_image[i].length - j - 1]` statement as its a mess and difficult to understand

Comment: If you are wondering if something is unnecessary, remove it, run it, see if it does something different.

Comment: You could make this all a lot clearer if you extracted `_image[i]` as a variable, say, `row`. And it could be easier if you introduced another loop variable: `for (int j = 0, k = row.length - 1; j < k; ++j, --k)`, then write the loop body to swap j and k.

Comment: "Do I need to write down the _image part" remove the _image part. Does it still work?

Comment: @AndyTurner "remove the _image part. Does it still work?" - no, i knew removing it doesnt, was wondering if there's a way it could.

Comment: Regarding the extracted _image[i] - how do I extract it into a new variable?

Comment: @Croompy With `variabletype variablename = _image[i];`.